# Sort and sum different sized spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make sorting and summing very easy for a user by building a macro. The macro needs to find the final row, then sort, then subtotal and total. It should also use the current, active sheet. For example, I should turn the first spreadsheet into the second:

[image: Pre and Post Spreadsheet]

I'm able to do it for this dataset with a simple recording of the macro.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+B
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Oct 2015").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Oct 2015").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A24" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Oct 2015").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B24" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Oct 2015").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C24")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3), _
        Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    Range("A1:C45").Select
End Sub
```

I have the following bit of code to find the last row, but not sure how to integrate it into the above to replace the hard-coded "range" value.

```
 Sub GetLastRow(strSheet, strColum)
 Dim MyRange As Range
 Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Set MyRange = Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strColum & "1")

    lngLastRow = Cells(sheetvar.Rows.Count, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 End Sub
```

I'd also need to change the Active Worksheet value to the current open worksheet, since this value will change.

The column names and column order should be consistent. I would also need to put this script on a remote user's PC and make sure it was available whenever they opened Excel.

I'd also like to shade the subtotaled areas if possible, but this is a secondary request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were half way there.
First you declare your variables for current sheet, your range and your last row and column.
And then you implement all of them into the macro you just recorded.

```
 Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+B


    Dim sht As Worksheet
        Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
        Dim rng As Range
 Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With sht

            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
    End With

        sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With sht.Sort
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3), _
            Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3), _
            Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Great job with this, the OP did ask that it be for the active sheet and not one sheet only so he could use it on more than the one.  Maybe change the sht reference to the activesheet instead.

Comment: Thanks Scott, Edited my Answer.

Comment: Thanks. When executed, I got "Run-Time error '1004': The sort reference is not valid...

Comment: I changed it, but it still gave the same error (at .Apply).

Comment: Can you run it on a fresh sheet? I tested it and this working.

Comment: I ran it, but it still gave the error. I also commented out the "with" Sort, and the subtotals ran OK.

Comment: Lets take a short sheet and try it.. something with lets say 4 rows, So if it still gets error then I will type it myself and check it out.

Comment: It's still the same issue. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: The Issue is with the keys in the sortfields.  They need to be range("A:A") and Range("B:B") respectively.  And increase rng to be the whole range and not just the last line.

Comment: I changed the Sortfields range to `sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A")` and `Range("B:B")`. It worked. But, what did you mean by 'increase range...not just last line'? Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

Comment: You will also need to change the word `selection` in the two subtotal statements to `rng`.